# Cutting trees using depth bounded search?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

I'm looking at writing a FPT (fixed parameter tractable) algorithm that takes in a **tree**; $T = (V, E)$. And a set of pairwise distinct vertex pairs (from $V$), $H$ and a $k>0$. Does there exist a set of edges, $E' \subseteq E$ where $|E'| \leq k$, such that the forests created by $(V, E\setminus E')$ disjoins each pair of vertices found in $H$?

Seems to be a simplified problem of the more generalised problem acting on just standard graphs.

The only approach I can think of is the following;
take an arbitrary pair in $H$, use some LCA derivate algorithm to draft a path between the two mentioned vertices and just cutting at 4 different sections (recursing into each cut). The four cuts of interest I thought would be the two terminal edges in the path returned by this LCA derivate algorithm, and also the two edges surrounding the LCA itself. Ofcourse the complexity is nice and $O(4^k * n)$ which is FPT. But I am not convinced that this would be *correct*.

Comment: It seems that a set of $H$ nodes would have to be separated by $|H|-1$ deletions, no? This would imply a trivial polytime solution, but I don't immediately see an example where this wouldn't work. Can you describe a tree and $H$ which does not require $|H|-1$ deletions?